# Mysql Query to give unique id to each Group

Tags: mysql

Using mysql query or Proc ,am trying to give each chat group a unique id.
A user can do multiple chats with company_id

```
Chat(id,type,company_id)
Type=0 Chat Stated by User
Type=1 Chat Started by Agent
Type=2 Chat End By Agent

Sample Data
1,0,21 : 1st Chat started by user  
2,0,21
3,1,21
4,0,341 :Chat Started by user
5,2,21  : 1st Chat End by Agent
6,1,341
7,2,341
8,0,21 :Chat stated by user
9,1,21
10,2,21
```

Expected Result

```
1,1,0,21 : 1st Chat started by user  
1,2,0,21
1,3,1,21
2,4,0,341 :Chat Started by user
1,5,2,21  : 1st Chat End by Agent
2,6,1,341
2,7,2,341
3,8,0,21 :Chat stated by user
3,9,1,21
3,10,2,21
```

Comment: Could you please explain your expected result? You have 4 columns there, what they stands for? Use words and better structure please.

Comment: Why you dont use company_id as id ?

Comment: @Bandydan For Actual Result Chat(id,type,company_id),Expected Result:Chat(uniqueChatId,id,type,company_id)

Comment: From the given example, can I say that every company has only one chat? Can't it happen that there will be a record like
11, 0, 21
and it will mean another chat for the same company?
Or, for example, can those records stand for two different chats? 
4,0,341 :Chat Started by user
6,1,341
If not, then you don't need any other id, but the company id.